# Css thumbnails hover issue in wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress

I am working here http://tinyurl.com/a74ko2o , this is an ecommerce store , powered by wordpress and my issue is in single product page , css designing in this link page , you guys can see thumbnails under the big image on hover thumbnails shows solid red border

I add this effect, but now, the problem is when it hovered , the image's moving down , and not fixed. i need it to be fixed , exact as this website http://emporium.premiumcoding.com/demo.php

css here for thumbnails

```
.leftcontentsp .thumbnails img {
    border: 4px solid #343434;
    height: 92px;
    margin: 5px 4px 8px 0;
    width: 92px;
}
```

on hover

```
.leftcontentsp .thumbnails img:hover, .product_list_widget li img:hover {
border: 5px solid #d00000;
}
```

please help to fix up this css issue , thanks in advance

Comment: You managed to fix your caps lock button, nice!

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15173167/css-issue-with-thumbnails-border-in-hover

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is because adding a `5px` wide border after a `4px` wide you get a `1px` difference that moves the image down. We can fix this my adding and removing a padding, so the image stays in place:

```
.leftcontentsp .thumbnails img {
    border: 4px solid #343434;
    height: 92px;
    margin: 5px 4px 8px 0;
    width: 92px;
    padding: 1px;
}

.leftcontentsp .thumbnails img:hover, .product_list_widget li img:hover {
    border: 5px solid #d00000;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Or if it's a mistake, just make the border the same wide on `:hover` as on the normal.

```
.leftcontentsp .thumbnails img:hover, .product_list_widget li img:hover {
    border: 4px solid #d00000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

see the difference men

give same border width

```
.leftcontentsp .thumbnails img:hover, .product_list_widget li img:hover {
border: 4px solid #d00000;
}
```

as in natural state

`1px` disturbing

and this is for

transition on hover

```
.leftcontentsp .thumbnails img:hover, .product_list_widget li img:hover {
    border: 4px solid #d00000;
-webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
        -o-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
        -ms-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
        transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
    }
```